# Nodejs Express req.body is empty and header null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on retrieving a post request body so that i can add the arguments in the body to my database.

At first I was getting an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`  but i added this line `applctn.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // to support URL-encoded bodies`    and now i get an empty body.

My code looks like this :

```
const express = require("express");
const moment = require("moment");
const db = require("./dbconnection.js"); //reference of dbconnection.js
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const applctn = express();

applctn.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

applctn.post("/hl7_message", function(req, res) {

    var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(req.body);

    console.log(req);
```

When i add ```app.use(bodyParser.json());   // to support JSON-encoded bodies

````
 ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
````

Any advise /tips on how i can retrieve the body contents will be appreciated.

[my response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHXdS.jpg)

Comment: try using `applctn.use(express.json())` this might be the thing missing from your setup.

Comment: @dhruv479, when i add that i get this error ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) ```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `applctn.use(bodyParser.json())`. Here is the solution :

```
const express = require("express");
const moment = require("moment");
const db = require("./dbconnection.js"); //reference of dbconnection.js
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const applctn = express();
applctn.use(bodyParser.json());
applctn.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

applctn.post("/hl7_message", function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body);
 res.send({code:200,message:"success"})
})

applctn.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("running");
});
```